# MVC3 using .resx for localisations of images

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, localization, resx

I have been using `.resx` files for localisation of text in my MVC3 app quite happily for a while now following these [instructions](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization-part-2.aspx), but have now got to a point where i need to do localisation of images as well.

the `.resx` editor in VS2010 will let you add an image as a resource easily enough, it just dumps it in a folder called Resources in the same directory as the `.resx` file, and i can reference the image in the same way as strings in my views by calling `@ResXfileName.ResourceName`, but that returns a `System.Drawing.BitMap` object, i was hoping it would just give me the path to the image so i could shove it in am image tags src attribute, but i can't work out how to get the path at all!

Comment: You could just save the relative or absolute path to the images as strings (the same way you do with the other texts) in the resource file(s) instead.

Comment: I could, but i would at least like to learn how to use the resx file as intended before i make up my mind which method to use

Comment: I understand. But that is how the resx file works. Images are returned as objects instead of the path to the file. That way it enables the resource to embed the image in the assembly, if the user needs to. using it the way I described first is still localized.

Comment: ok, is there no way to get the filepath from the object?

Answer (score 5):

### Solution 1: locale folder structure

The best (and easiest) way would be to add a new `HtmlHelper` extension method that returns locale name (or LCID) and you can use it with anything afterwards (images, scripts etc.). The best way is of course to have localised files in such folder structure:

```
/images
    /en-US
        image1.png
    /en-GB
        image1.png
    /es-ES
```

image1.png

And this is how you would use it then:

```
<img src="/images/@Html.Locale/backgrounds/back.png" />
```

This is an example of such extension method.

```
public MvcHtmlString Locale(this HtmlHelper helper)
{
    // in case you're setting UI culture
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name);
}
```

If this simplification doesn't work in your case and you need specific call for images, then create a `UrlHelper` method called `Image` or `File` where you provide it server app relative path with some tokens that get replaced with your locale name or LCID.

### Solution 2: Resource file links

You can also put image paths inside a resource file and use those values in your views to provide correct paths for your images (or other files for that matter).

```
public MvcHtmlString Resource(this UrlHelper helper, string classKey string resourceKey)
{
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject(classKey, resourceKey));
}
```

And then in your view use it as:

```
<img src="@Url.Resource("images", "header")" />
```

Comment: I was really hoping that I could use the resx file to organise all my images (those that need localisation anyway), what is the intended functionality of being able to add images to it if its not for what i am attempting?

Comment: @Ben: My answer is just one of the ways. There are other ways as well. One being saving image paths (or names) in resource file, the other one would be to add images directly into satellite assemblies and have handler that serves them etc. There are many ways... I just said that the easiest is to have a helper extension method and have files in per-language folder structure. You can implement whatever you like. And since you already seem to know what you want... Why don't you just use that then?

Comment: I think that is a good way of doing it. I really want to keep using the resx files rather than using a specific folder structure because with the resx method, if a particular resource isn't available in the chosen language it defaults to the english version automatically. However, I would still like to know what the proper way of using resx file and images is, in other words what microsoft intended when they wrote the resx editor that allows you to insert images

Comment: @Ben: Same fallback can be achieved using folder structure as well. My extensions were super simple. You could of course check for file existence and provide fallback when file isn't present. Regarding images I think that people mostly use folder structure because it's the lest complicated one and first one that pops into one's mind. Simplicity is usually key. And it's also simple to understand without an additional abstraction layer for new team members.